# Stochastic Differential Equation Time-Independent

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I know that a generic 1-D SDE can be written in Ito form as:

$dX_{t} = \mu(X_t,t)dt + \sigma(X_t,t)dW_t$.

I was curious as to how such an SDE is written when modelling **time-independent** processes. I was thinking that it must be driftless, so that $\mu = 0$, which leaves us with:

$dX_{t} = \sigma(X_t,t)dW_{t}$,

but, then must $\sigma = \sigma(X)$, i.e., no explicit dependence on time?

Thanks!

Comment: Why driftless? Note that if $E(\mu(X_t,t))=0$ for every $t$ (which may happen when $\mu$ is not identically zero) then $E(X_t)$ is constant.

Comment: Ahh! So, in general, what would a time-independent process look like? I was thinking it had to be driftless since the dt contribution should be zero...

Comment: What do you exactly mean by time-independent process?